Multilanguage meaning recognition from text using ChromaDB and paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2
I want to extract the meaning from user text input. User describes what he wants and if his query matches given topics, i'll receive the most relevant topics.
I have following topic descriptions:

 - Job request. Search for a job. To find a new job. Ask for open job positions.
 - The topic is profession, professional field or qualification for some profession. 
 - Including questions what does a specific profession.
 - The topic is company, work conditions, atmosphere in that company, information about  that company.
 - The topic is salary or money, contains one or more questions about payment.
 - Request for document. To create or generate a document.
 - The topic is curriculum vitae ( cv ), personal job experience, past jobs and positions.
 - The topic is labor law, regulations and employee rights.
 - The topic is a place or a location. Connected with a specific county, district, city, or street.
 - Request for an information, or an advice, or an opinion on some specific topic.
 - The topic is education, level of education, graduated schools, knowledge gained by education system.
 - The topic is related with personal abilities or individual soft skills.
 - The topic is all types of work benefits. For instance, sick days, family leave, extra working holiday, corporate catering, discounts for employees.
 - Questions asking about identity of "yourself" like "What is your name?", "Who are you?". 
 - Explicit words, vulgarisms, abusive words or racist words. Or the meaning of the message is abusive or explicit.



I use BERT sentence transformer and paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2 model.
But the results aren't enough accurate. For instance...

[OK] If I put any vulgar sentence or phrase, it is detected perfectly.
[OK] If I put "What does a baker?" Then "profession" topic is matched
[OK/BAD] If I put "Find me a job in London" Then "job request" is perfectly matched but location/place topic is not present among TOP 5 results.
[BAD] If I put "What does a lawyer?" or "What is lawyer profession about?" then labour law topic is matched

What I can do with this? My problem is that I need multilingual topic recognition and paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2 is the only from all models I have tested before that works almost same across different languages.
I found here this topic NLP, how to fix that pretrained model paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2 isn't accurate on some examples? .

Is this also the solution for my issue?
Should i retrain the model? Will it be multilingual?
Will it help if i put into profession topic list of all possible professions I have in database? And into location topic list of all cities, counties from my database?

